# How can I change the default title “Number at risk” in the risk table in survminer

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm running a survival probability (Kaplan-Meier) curve using the survminer R package. I'm setting on the risk table, however, I'd like to change the default title "Number at risk". How could I do it?

I'm using the following code:

```
 survAL <- survfit(Surv(time, death) ~ AL.Factor, data = wave1)

 ggsurvplot(survAL, legend.title = "Allostatic Load", legend.labs = c("Low", 
"Mid", "High"), ylim = c(0.90, 1.0), conf.int = TRUE, pval = TRUE, 
 xlim = c(0,10), xlab = "Time in years", ylab = "Survival Probability", 
 break.time.by = 2, ggtheme = theme_light(), risk.table = TRUE, 
 risk.table.col = "strata",  data = wave1)
```

Comment: code isn't reproducible, but it looks like `ggsurvplot()` returns a standard ggplot object so couldn't you just add your own `ggtitle()` at the end and override whatever comes before it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `risk.table.title` option of `ggsurvplot`:

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)
survAL <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

ggsurvplot(survAL, legend.title = "Allostatic Load", legend.labs = c("M","F"), 
 ylim = c(0.0, 1.0), conf.int = TRUE, pval = TRUE, 
 xlim = c(0,300), xlab = "Time", ylab = "Survival Probability", 
 break.time.by = 50, ggtheme = theme_light(), risk.table = TRUE, 
 risk.table.col = "strata",  risk.table.title="My title", data = lung)
```

[image]